# Equation of a straight line - In Calculus of Variations proof of "Shortest Path" by Goldstein 3rd Edition

Tags: physics

I'm hoping for help with what is probably a very simple question.  But, in Classical Mechanics physics textbook by Goldstein, 3rd edition, in section 2.2 "Some Techniques of the Calculus of Variations" the author states this:

[Relation of a to c is a straight line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp54d.png)

But, this is clearly the equation of a straight line,
y = ax + b,

So, please forgive my lack of knowledge of this probably very simple algebra question.  But, I don't see how a = c/stuff is actually the equation of a straight line.

Many many thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this doesn't seem to be one.  Are you looking for http://physics.stackexchange.com or http://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: "This" probably refers to some other equation further up the page, which you have omitted from the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the word relation differently than the book is using it.

You see the word "relation" as "equality" like `a = c`.  They aren't using that sense of the word.  In their description there are two things, a and c, and a third thing "the relation" which is something that is a "straight line"

So, from my reading of the information (which might be wrong, but there is no extra information to help me avoid something like a guess) they are describing a straight line between points a and c.